# Merge Zip Codes to Create new sales Markets

Tags: shapefile, r, merge

Let me preface this question by saying I am very novice with respect to GIS.  With this in mind, I am looking to merge zip codes into sales territories. Instead of plotting data by zip code, I want to have a new file that lets me plot data for the respective territories.

Currently, I get around this by plotting the same value for all zip codes in the territory.

What is the best/easiest way to do accomplish this task?  I am quite familiar with the programming language `R`, but usually can work through examples if this requires programming in other languages.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understand your problem/issue.  If I understand correctly you have a number of polygons that represent Zip Codes (ie: 10 polygons all with different zip codes).  You may have 6 sales regions within the zip code; and two zip codes may be in one sales area?  If that is the case, you could create a new field in the attribute table and code the zip code polygons as a sales code.  (ie: 10 zip code polygons have 6 sales codes).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  A sales territory is made up of multiple zip codes.  A zip code is only included in one sales territory.  I want to create a new shp file where the polygons represent the territory.  I have 304 territories across the US.  My aim is to create a file that has the 304 polygons.

Comment: For most GIS products, the method would be called a ["dissolve"](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=dissolve), which would remove the internal boundaries based upon a common attribute in an attribute field (column).

Comment: What GIS software do you have access to?

Comment: ArcMap, but I would like to stay within R if possible, unless there is a GUI-driven dummy-proof way to do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `unionSpatialPolygons` function in the `maptools` package does this. You supply to it a `SpatialPolygons` and a vector which indicates which polygons (zip codes, in your example) belong to which aggregated polygon (sales areas).

EDIT:

The help page on [unionSpatialPolygons](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/maptools/docs/unionSpatialPolygons) has a good example of creating a grouping/indexing vector. It using counties in North Carolina, but the ideas are the same. Pulling from that example:

```
nc1 <- readShapePoly(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")[1],
 proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27"))
```

Loads an example `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`. Extract from this whatever information you need that is one-per-polygon. The example gets single coordinates associated with the polygon (centroid?)

```
lps <- coordinates(nc1)
```

You can see these together:

```
plot(nc1)
points(lps)
```

[image]

You could do something with `nc1@data` instead. Either have 100 entries, one for each polygon.

```
> dim(nc1@data)
[1] 100  14
> dim(lps)
[1] 100   2
> length(nc1@polygons)
[1] 100
```

Then use whatever transformation/mapping to derive a length 100 vector that indicates the groups.

---

The `gpclibPermitStatus` error probably means you don't have the `rgeos` package installed and/or have not agreed to the more restrictive license of gpclib.

Comment: What is the "best" way to create the vector for the unionSpatialPolygons function since it needs to be the same length?  It errored out when I tried to pass it just a vector of the zip codes of interest (error= different lengths) as well as when a vector of T/F but the same length.  Thanks.

Comment: gpclibPermitStatus() is the error I received when passing it a vector of T/F.

Comment: This is great.  I had to install rgeos, gpclib, and call gpclibPermit() before the union would work.    Two final questions if I could.  I used a state with two markets (e.g. Rhode Island).  I only supplied the zip's for one market, but the result was that the state was split perfectly into the 2 markets.  How do I handle states w/ multiple markets.  Second, is there a way I can assign a name to each market (RI 1, RI 2) etc?  Huge help!!!

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out how to keep only the zip codes as one entity.  I just need to figure out how to name each market and stitch them all back together, as there will be 304 in total.  Huge help, thanks again!

Comment: You could just use gUnionCascaded in the rgeos package and avoid maptools and gpclib entirely. The rgeos library calls the C API topology library GEOS and is much more efficient than maptools.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans I hadn't thought of using the `rgeos` package directly; looking at the code for `unionSpatialPolygons`, it uses either `gUnionCascaded` or `gUnaryUnion` when using the GEOS library, so it is just a matter of an additional level of indirection/abstraction.

Comment: @BrianDiggs, The developers for maptools and rgeos are the same. The rgeos package is a very recent port to GEOS and, since it is a real topology library, is intended to replace much of the maptools functionality. For efficiency and stability sake I think that they are rewriting some of the maptools functions to have rgeos under the hood. This strategy leaves the maptools package in place so preexisting code will not be depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the zip code shapefile, select the zipcodes that fit into each territory and merge them.  If don't want to do this manually you can script it with python.  Check out arcpy if you're using ESRI's ArcMap, for QGIS pyqgis.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: You could use the over function in the sp package to provide an intersect table between regions and zip codes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how to program this but to do it manually you could select by attribute on your zip code shapefile to select all zip codes in a sales territory. Then you can can modify the attribute table to designate the sales territory. Once you've done this for each sale territory you can use the dissolve tool as mentioned above to dissovle based on the sales territory.